# How to use Conditional statement in Case When statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to translate my query similar to below C# statement:

```
var result = Data.Where(r=> r.Year = 2017 
       && ( unit ==00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ? true: unit == r.UnitId);
```

Below is then query I am trying to put into table values function but get error on = operator in case statement.

```
SELECT * From ReportData
WHERE       
  Year = @year 
  AND
  (CASE @unit
      WHEN '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' THEN 1
    ELSE  @unit = UnitId
    END
  )
```

Is is possible to put condition in  then block of case statement in sql? 
Is there any way to implement this in SQL?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   ReportData
WHERE  Year = @year 
  AND  (UnitId = @unit OR @unit IS NULL)
```

`CASE` in SQL doesn't work like `if` in C#; it just returns an atomic value.

Comment: unitid cannot be 0000 something any how.. if unit is not defined then it should always return true with out checking the unitid.. may be it is not possible in sql to write in the same way..

Answer (score 1):

**TRY THIS** Your own query will work by making simple changes as below:

```
SELECT * From ReportData
WHERE       
  Year = @year 
  AND UnitId = 
  (CASE @unit
      WHEN '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' THEN 1
    ELSE  @unit
    END
  )
```

Comment: unitid cannot be 0000 something any how..  it is not the translation of the linq statement.. how can string compared to 1 ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
SELECT * From ReportData
WHERE       
  Year = @year 
  AND
  (CASE @unit
      WHEN '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' THEN 1
    ELSE  @unit 
    END
  )= UnitId
```